# Class name followed by empty parentheses and empty curly braces

Tags: c++

This is a sample code found on cplusplus.com for overloading operators. I am not sure what "CVector () {};" means here. It does not look like a constructor, and when I delete this line, the compiler give me errors.

```
// overloading operators example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {};                             <-- This Line
    CVector (int a,int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    CVector operator + (const CVector&);
};

CVector CVector::operator+ (const CVector& param) {
  CVector temp;
  temp.x = x + param.x;
  temp.y = y + param.y;
  return temp;
}

int main () {
  CVector foo (3,1);
  CVector bar (1,2);
  CVector result;
  result = foo + bar;
  cout << result.x << ',' << result.y << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a default constructor.  You don't need the semicolon. Also, your operator+ should ideally not be a member function. And  cplusplus.com is not a good learning resource.

Comment: There must be a duplicate, but I can't find one...

Comment: It would be better to fill in `x` and `y` with an initialization list

Comment: @SergeyA - Probably page 5 or 10 of a C++ programming book

Comment: @SergeyA I doubt that there's something appropriate. That question is lacking of research at best though. (Eek, I even wrote an answer :-P )

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks for your help. I did try to find out my answer by reviewing the chapter on constructor before asking. But I failed to recognize this is a default constructor because I have never seen it be used before. 
Neil Butterworth

Comment: @Neil Butterworth thanks for your help. I found cplusplus.com to be the most helpful among all the C++ tutorial websites I have visited. Can you suggest some better learning source?

Comment: @Pracka Get a good book. Heck, get several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure what `CVector () {};` means here. It does not look like a constructor,

What gives you this idea? Of course that's a default constructor **defined** without any special member initializers.

<sub>The semicolon can be dropped, it's only needed for plain function declarations, that do not provide a definition.</sub>

> and when I delete this line, the compiler give me errors.

That's probably because some other part of your code needs to have a default constructor for `CVector`. The obvious candidate is

```
CVector result;
```

---

To extend a little bit:

You have to declare/define the default constructor function explicitly, as soon you declare a custom constructor like

```
CVector (int a,int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
```

The automatically generated default constructor

```
CVector();
```

won't be generated in that case.

The easiest way in such case is to write

```
CVector () = default;
```

But you have to define it to be usable with statements like

```
CVector result;
```

Comment: What makes you think the assignment operator and copy constructor will not be generated?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Removed that.